How do I format the numbers in a trendline equation using OpenPyXL?
I am using openpyxl to generate some figures in a spreadsheet. I have added the R^2 and trendline equations, however, I also want to format those numbers to show a higher number of significant figures. In the case of the trendline equation (exponential fit), I'd prefer to have four or five digits on the first term and nine in the exponential term in scientific notation, however, I'd settle for both numbers having nine digits; for R^2, I'd like five to six digits.
import openpyxl

def draw_cal_plot(sheet, xvalues, yvalues, title, x_axis_title, y_axis_title, chart_location):
    # scatter plot of data
    chart = openpyxl.chart.ScatterChart()
    chart.title = title
    chart.style = 13
    chart.x_axis.title = x_axis_title
    chart.y_axis.title = y_axis_title
    series = openpyxl.chart.Series(yvalues, xvalues, title_from_data=False)
    series.marker.symbol = "circle"
    series.marker.graphicalProperties.solidFill = "0000FF"  # Blue color
    series.graphicalProperties.line.noFill = True  # Remove lines between data points

    # exponential trendline
    series.trendline = openpyxl.chart.trendline.Trendline()
    series.trendline.trendlineType = "exp"  # Exponential trendline
    series.trendline.graphicalProperties = openpyxl.chart.shapes.GraphicalProperties()
    series.trendline.graphicalProperties.line = openpyxl.drawing.line.LineProperties()
    series.trendline.graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = "000000"  # Black color
    series.trendline.graphicalProperties.line.width = 1  # Thin line
    series.trendline.dispEq = True  # Display trendline equationequation to nine digits, scientific notation
    series.trendline.dispRSqr = True  # Display R^2 value
    chart.series.append(series)
    sheet.add_chart(chart, chart_location)

I've tried googling for this, but all of the results are for "how to format numbers" on pages that happen to contain the word "trendline" but nothing about formatting the actual trendline numbers themselves.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

In Excel charts trend-lines have trend-line labels that display all the trend-line information. This are the equation, if set, as well as the R-squared value, if set. The trend-line labels can have one number format set. See Display more digits in trendline equation coefficients in Excel
Using openpyxl:
...
series.trendline.trendlineLbl = openpyxl.chart.trendline.TrendlineLabel()
series.trendline.trendlineLbl.numFmt = openpyxl.chart.data_source.NumFmt('0.000000') 
...

This is what Microsoft Office charts provide. Multiple different number formats for different parts of the trend-line labels are not supported.
